# Cannot get root certificate of remote server programmatically, while browsers can. Why?

Tags: python, ssl, ca

I'm trying to programmatically retrieve the root CA certificate of a corporate website.

I tried several things, and they basically all rely on OpenSSL's `get_peer_cert_chain()` method.

```
import sys
import socket
from OpenSSL import SSL


HOSTNAME = sys.argv[1]

context = SSL.Context(method=SSL.TLSv1_METHOD)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock = SSL.Connection(context=context, socket=sock)
sock.settimeout(5)
sock.connect((HOSTNAME, 443))
sock.setblocking(1)
sock.do_handshake()
for cert in sock.get_peer_cert_chain():
    print(f"subject: {cert.get_subject()}")
    print(f"issuer:  {cert.get_issuer()}")
sock.shutdown()
sock.close()
```

The method returns only one certificate when it should return two: the root CA is missing.
I've read somewhere that the server can omit the root CA if it wants to (it's not forced by the protocol).

But Firefox and Internet Explorer are able to "see" the root CA, and allow me to copy it in a file on the disk.

Why these browsers can see them, and why my Python SSL connection can't?
What's the difference between the two?
Could it be possible that the remote server changes its behavior and return the root CA for specific user agents or something?

Comment: The server only has to send the chain up as far as a trusted signer in your truststore. Your browser truststores might be different from whatever Python uses.

Comment: @user207421: why should Python's browser trust more certificates than Firefox? I don't even know how I would install trusted certificates for Python.

Comment: I've tried in an isolated environment (docker) but it still returns only one certificate.

Comment: About Python, look at `certifi`: https://pypi.org/project/certifi/ ; `requests` uses it for example.

Comment: "that the server can omit the root CA if it wants to (it's not forced by the protocol)." See RFC 8446 §4.4.2 "a certificate that specifies a trust anchor MAY be
   omitted from the chain, provided that supported peers are known to
   possess any omitted certificates."

Comment: I don't think `certifi` will be of any help here. As for "provided that supported peers are known to possess any omitted certificates", sure, but then how come I can see these omitted certificates in my browser? What does my browser do to access these certificates, and how can I do the same in Python?